# MATLAB solver gives empty vector

Tags: matlab, solver

I am getting unexpected behavior and I'm not sure where to start.

I have a simple polynomial

`20/[(s(s+1)]`

and I need to replace `s` with `jω`, take its absolute value, convert it to `dB` and then solve for `ω` by setting this equal to a known value.

```
syms w

Omega = double(solve(20*log10(abs((20)/(1i*w*(1i*w+1)))) == -desired_db, w));
```

Yet, when I go to solve it I get results that I can't make sense of. It's saying it is an empty space column vector. According to our professor, the answer should be about 6.7

Any thoughts?

Comment: What value are you using for `-desired_db`?

Comment: Is omega a real number? In this case you can try to plot the function `20*log10(...)` and see if it behaves as expected

Comment: You can also try to add `, 'Real', true` arguments to solve function